# How to get connection from EntityManager configured in Spring context?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions, dbunit

I want to get connection from EntityManager configured in spring context to use it in dbunit DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute method.

Here is Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="testmEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <qualifier value="testm" type="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect"><bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/></property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
   <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter"/>
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
    </property>
</bean>

 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"
      p:url="jdbc:h2:mem:test;IGNORECASE=TRUE;">
    <property name="autoCommit" value="false"/>
    <property name="suppressClose" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"></bean>

 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="testmTransactionManager"/>
<bean id="testmTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <qualifier value="testm"/>
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="testmEntityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Here is code:

```
@javax.persistence.PersistenceContext(unitName = "testm")
@Qualifier(value = "testm")
protected javax.persistence.EntityManager emanager;


@Transactional
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    IDatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection (((SessionImpl)(emanager.getDelegate())).connection());
```

I receive exception `org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!`

When I use `emanager.getTransaction ().begin ();`
I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead`

**SOLVED:**
used datasource to get it:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
```

and

```
dataSource.getConnection ()
```

Comment: Why? Just use the datasource to get it...

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 canonical ways of using transactions in Spring:

1. Using `@Transactional` annotation on methods
2. Using [TransactionTemplate.execute](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html#execute(org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallback)) method

The 2nd approach gives you the possibility to execute multiple transactions withing the single method. You don't have to start and stop transaction manually then.

The database connection is active only within the spring transaction unit, so either within `@Transactional` method, of within a callback method to `TransactionTemplate.execute()`.